# Calculating time spent inside the loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, performance

How to check the number of seconds(or ms) spent inside the particular loop in javascript.
I have a sorting algo implemented in javascript , now I am using bubble sort , I want to use quick sort. 
I know in terms of time efficiency Quick sort is good. But I want to calculate the real number of sec or milli sec spent inside the innermost loop. 
How do I do in javascript ?

Comment: Addition to all the answers , one more useful functionality I found in firebug is "Timing and profiling" , http://getfirebug.com/logging , helps to determine JavaScript performance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest method is to compare by Date.

```
var old_time = new Date();
...
var new_time = new Date();
var seconds_passed = new_time - old_time;
```

By the way, why don't you just use the built-in `.sort()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/sort) method?

Comment: ok.Thanks
I am not sorting numbers , I am sorting array of objects where I sort depending on one of the property of the object. so built-in sort I cannot use.

Comment: It's worth keeping in mind that the Date object is not terribly accurate. John Resig wrote an article about this: http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/.

Comment: @sat: The `sort` method allows you to specify a `compareFunction`, which allows you to do exactly what you're after (without having to go off and create your own sorting method). See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/Array/sort#Parameters for more information.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Check my full answer below.

Answer (score 9):

### All other answers in this thread are *old*.

Use this now, it's standard https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance.now

```
var t0 = performance.now();
doSomething();
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.")
```

Answer (score 5):

Time is not really accurate on most browsers, you can expect a margin of error about of 15ms:

```
var start = (new Date).getTime();
/* Your code. */
var diff = (new Date).getTime() - start;
```

Recommended read:

- [Accuracy of JavaScript Time](http://ejohn.org/blog/accuracy-of-javascript-time/)

Comment: That was a very good article !! Thanks . Never thought about it.

Answer (score 2):

Others have already answered how to do the time calculation, so I'll reply to your comment: "I am sorting array of objects where I sort depending on one of the property of the object. so built-in sort I cannot use."

That's not true at all, you can still use the built in sort:

```
var arr = [{ text: 'test', id: 2 }, { text: 'abc', id: 6 }, { text: 'xyz', id: 4 }];
arr.sort(function(x,y) { return x.text > y.text ? 1 : x.text < y.text ? -1 : 0 });
```

Comment: So in the above piece of code , its comparing the text property of 2 objects ? What algo is used internally ? means will it compare each n every object or some better algo ?

Comment: @sat: For Firefox, merge sort. This is used instead of quick sort to ensure the sort order is stable. See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=224128.

Comment: @David: `arr.sort(function(x,y) { return x.text > y.text ? 1 : x.text < y.text ? -1 : 0 });`.

Comment: @Kenny Thanks for that great info.U get to learn lot of things with simple questions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Firebug you can do

```
console.time('someNameHere');
// Do things here
console.timeEnd('someNameHere');
```